# How do I force apt-get to update the state of package versions?

Tags: 11.04, apt, update-manager

I installed Natty Narwhal last night, and cam across a problem with update manager. I had initially instructed update manager to "Install updates", but the dialog that popped up stayed on "waiting..." with no progress for over 5 minutes. I pressed cancel, hoping to exit Update Manager and try again, but after the Update Manger updated, it claims I have a completely updated system, with no packages left to install. When Update Manager first popped up after installation, I had approx. 84.

How can I force apt-get (as I get the same "no updates" message there) to re-build the status of all my packages?

I tried the solution below with `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but that ran without output, and I'm still not sure the packages advertised previously have been installed. `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` only gave me some updates to Chromium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found an answer on a separate question:

dpkg does a regular backup of the complete package status of the system to /var/backups/dpkg.status.*.gz. If you think your package status if out of sync with the actual packages installed, you can replace the status file at `/var/lib/dpkg/status` with the status file contained in the backup. Run the following commands with `sudo`:

```
cp /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bak
cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.*.gz /var/lib/dpkg/
gunzip -d /var/lib/dpkg/dpkg.status.*.gz
mv /var/lib/dpkg/dpkg.status.* /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

You should now be able to do an `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` to update to the most recent packages.

Answer (score 7):

Copy and paste **`sudo dpkg --configure -a`** into the Terminal.

Then paste `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

You can also try:
`sudo apt-get install -f` to fix broken dependencies.

Comment: You should explain what these commands do.